# How to check if ResultSet is empty?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to launch a class only if a select query returned at least a row.

My call to thequery function noted below:

```
results=thequery("SELECT `username`,`numberpoints` FROM `highscores` WHERE `username` = '"+name+"'");//send query that checks if username exist     
                if(!results.next()) {
                BallTrial trial = new BallTrial();
                }
```

**thequery** function:

```
public ResultSet  thequery(String query){

         PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        Connection con=null;
        Statement st=null;
        try {
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/scores","root","");

            statement = con.prepareStatement(query);

            rs=  statement.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));

                    return rs;

            }}


        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("you have not accessed the data base");

        }

        return null;

    }
```

I am getting a null pointer exception at `if(!results.next()) {`, can anyone clarify what is my mistake here?

Comment: paste your entire stack trace

Comment: @GovindaSakhare cheers

Comment: Does the `name` come from the user? If so, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. You're already using a `PreparedStatement`. Don't concatenate the value to the query string. Do it right.

Comment: yep you're right, thanks @DavidConrad

Comment: Your code is leaking resources: you are creating a statement and connection in this method, but never close it. And closing it would result in the result set being unusable outside this method, so consider another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the null check condition before calling `next`, the condition needs to be tweaked something around the lines: `results != null && !results.next()`

Comment: It probably would be better to propagate an exception instead of returning null.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Agreed. But not sure what SO is trying to do here. Assuming it's some kind of academic assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a couple of changes:

1. From `thequery` method, return ResultSet (i.e. `rs`) instead of returning `null`. Returning `null` will cause NPE. Also, remove `while(...)` as it needs to be done by the caller, e.g.

   ```
   public ResultSet  thequery(String query){

    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;
    try {
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/scores","root","");
        statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs=  statement.executeQuery();
        return rs;
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("you have not accessed the data base");
        throw e;
    }
   }
   ```
2. In the caller method, check whether ResultSet contains any records by calling `rs.next()`, e.g.:

   ```
   results = thequery(..)
   if(!results.next()){
       BallTrial trial = new BallTrial();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) {
            if (!results.next()){
               System.out.prinln("result has no data");
            }else{               
                  System.out.prinln("result has some data");
            }
        }
```